# How to add / remove validators in a substrate network

Tags: substrate

I would like to add / remove validators from an already existing substrate private network.

Following the tutorial for starting a[private network](https://www.substrate.io/tutorials/start-a-private-network/v2.0.0-alpha.6), I was able to create a raw customSpec and start a new chain with the validators.

However, I am not sure how to add new / remove old validators to the network. So these are the steps I tried:

1. edit customSpecs.json to desired validators
2. build new raw_customSpecs.json
3. restart node with new raw_customSpecs.json
4. use the hex code in the new raw_customSpecs to upgrade the runtime with sudo via polkadotjs, similar to the [given example](https://polkadot.js.org/api/examples/promise/10_upgrade_chain/).

I would like to get some pointers as to how to do this properly because I am still unable to set new validators with the steps I have taken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have various ways to add/remove validators. Using chain-spec is one of them, but you are on the wrong path trying to apply a runtime upgrade with the spec. A runtime upgrade will typically only update one storage item, [`:code`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_storage/well_known_keys/constant.CODE.html), which is the code of your runtime. On the other hand, your validators are stored in other storage items in the [`pallet_staking`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_staking/index.html) and [`pallet_session`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_session/index.html) module. So indeed applying the runtime upgrade will not get you anywhere.

Indeed, if you are fine with restarting your node, you can alter the *initial validators* and run your chain again, after you have updated your step 1:

> edit customSpecs.json to desired validators

To do it on the fly, you need to look into how staking pallet is working. You can `bond` new accounts and if the `ValidatorCount` is more than the current number of validators, the next election round will elect the new account. Of course, a node with the private key of this newly bonded account must be present in the network for everything to work well. You can use sudo to increase `ValidatorCount`.

Comment: What is the difference between `minimum_validator_count` and `validator_count`? I set validator count to 1000 on my node, and minimum_vc to 1 and my node is producing and finalizing blocks just fine, but it can't include new validators into the validator set. Is that a side effect of validators < `validator_count` ?

Comment: When you says "restarting your node" does it mean clear all blocks and start with a fresh chain ?